# Store x and y coordinates of mouse movements in a text file

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-fullstack

Hello I'm new to fullstack development,The thing i'm trying to achieve is  that have I these x and y coordinates which are generated by the mouse (cursor) movements ,which i want to store in a text file locally / on server side.How should i go about doing this ?....I'm using react as my frontend and planning to use Django as my backend.

I can see the constantly updated values of x and y coordinates using console.log() ...
Here is my code snippet;

```
Container.onmousemove = function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                let x = e.layerX;
                let y = e.layerY;
                if (e.touches) {
                    x = e.touches[0].pageX;
                    y = e.touches[0].pageY;
                }
                //x & y coordinates of present cursor position
                  console.log(x,y);
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you're doing touches, here is for the touch events (mobile). If you're thinking desktop, use `mouseOver` instead. Some comments are in the code, but essentially you can keep track of all the changes locally and however you need to, send your data to the server to parse it and upload it to the file. This could end up being a very large file though so double check it isn't affecting performance too much once you're all set up! One alternative is to use the browser's native event instead to take the work off React.

**Client**

```
import React from 'react';

function Container({addTouch}) {
  const updateCoordinates = e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.persist(); // React synthetic events are pooled if not
    // Can also use native event
    // For more on events check out:
    // https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html
    const {clientX: x,clientY: y} = e.touches[0];
    addTouch(e.timeStamp, {x: x | 0,y: y | 0}); // | 0 is Math.floor. Remove if you want exact px
    // Using the timestamp as a key, but keep track of them however
  }

  return (
    <div className="Container" onTouchMove={e=>updateCoordinates(e)}>
      Container
    </div>
  )
}

function App() {
  const touchList = new Map();
  const addTouch = (timestamp, coordinates) => touchList.set(timestamp, coordinates);
  const sendToServer = () => {
    // You could put this on an interval to that
    // sends the touch list and clears the map
    const url = '//yourUrl/yourEndPoint/';
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
      body: JSON.stringify([...touchList]),
      headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        // Include your credentials here depending on how your API is set up
      }
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => console.log('Success:', response)) // or stringify response if getting back data
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container addTouch={addTouch}/>
      <button onClick={sendToServer}>SEND TOUCH LIST</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Server**

```py
# Handle your parsing and saving on the server however
# This is basic python/django since not sure how your servers set up
# I remember the REST framework having some built in classes
# like a serializer to handle some of this stuff for you
# You can create your own model in models.py
# then just get the request data in views.py and use your model functions to handle

import csv

from django.http import HttpResponse # ,JsonResponse if you're sending the data back
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

@api_view(['POST', 'PUT'])
def post_endpoint(request):
    """
    Save mouse coordinates to some file
    """
    # Might want to try, except request first before doing this

    if request.method == "POST":
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        filename = "touchList.csv"
        with open(filename, "a", newline='') as file:
            reader = csv.reader(file_obj, delimiter=',')
            fieldnames = ['timestamp', 'x', 'y'] # if using models you can define fields=(...)
            writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            for i in range(0, data.length): # or start at last file row
                writer.writerow({
                    'timestamp': data[i]['timestamp'],
                    'x': data[i]['x'],
                    'y': data[i]['y']
                })
        return HttpResponse('Success', status=201) # 201: Created, or 200, etc.

     # ...default response, error, etc.
```